# AVSpeechSynthesizer delegate method didStartSpeechUtterance not being called

Tags: ios7, delegates, avspeechsynthesizer

I am having trouble wth AVSpeechSynthesizer and utterances (ios 7.1.1)

The AVSpeechSynthesizer is initialised in a handler class with the delegate as self:

```
self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

self.synthesizer.delegate = self;
```

I have the following methods implemented in the delegate:

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
    NSLog(@"Finish");
}

-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didStartSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
    NSLog(@"Start");

}
```

and my speech is called via this method:

```
- (void)speak:(NSString *)spokenWord{

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:spokenWord];   

    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance]; 

}
```

I then call the method repeatedly e.g.

```
[AVhandler speak:_word];
[AVhandler speak:_word];
[AVhandler speak:_word];
```

I would expect to see in the log:
Start
Finish
Start
Finish
Start
Finish etc

But instead I see:
Start
Finish
Finish
Finish
Finish

Why is the didStartSpeechUtterance not being called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is a little late, apologies. To resolve this, also put:

```
synthesizer.delegate = self;
```

in the -(void) as below

```
 - (void)speak:(NSString *)spokenWord{

AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:spokenWord];   

[self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance]; 
synthesizer.delegate = self;

}
```

and in the didFinish as below:

```
-(void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance {
NSLog(@"Finish");
synthesizer.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to add a reference to the AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate Protocol in your .h file, such as:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>
```

Then you can put your synthesizer.delegate = self; in your ViewDidLoad method only.

Hope it helps.